# Converting int-Tuples into int and back

Tags: c++, tuples

I have the following problem: I have a list of integer tuples which I have to store as integers (i.e. (1,1) -> 1, (2,1) -> 2, (1,2) -> 3 etc.). I have to get the tuple values back from the integer values, thus a hash function which looses information is not usable. Is there any other fast function which does this, or do I have to do this on my own?

Thank you very much!

Comment: This is not possible in general.  If you have 2^N possible values for your input integers, you'll have 2^(2N) possible tuple values.  So you'll need a bigger integer type to store the results (in which case, concatenation is a trivial solution to your problem).

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: If I add them, how can I separate them afterwards again? Concerning the space problem: There is no problem, because for the tuples I am using `int` and for the "integer" values I am using `__int64`.

Comment: Don't add them, concatenate them.  i.e. use a bit-shift (you'll need to convert to unsigned first to avoid undefined behaviour).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple:

```
__int64 v = ((__int64)first << 32) | ((__int64)second & 0xffffffffL)
```

and:

```
int first = (int)((v >> 32) & 0xffffffffL)
int second = (int)(v & 0xffffffffL)
```

or (using unsigned storage type):

```
uint64_t v = ((uint64_t)first << 32) | (uint64_t)second
```

and:

```
int first = (int)(v >> 32)
int second = (int)(v & 0xffffffffL)
```

Comment: Note: should use *unsigned* int64 to avoid UB (unless it's known that the values are always non-negative).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth sure, but the op stated he uses `__int64`. The better type would be `unsigned __int64`, right. Oh, yep, I see.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: My values are always equal or greater than zero, so that I can use `__int64`

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the two integers into one __int64 integer by first casting/converting them both to __int64, then bit-shifting one of them with 32 positions and adding them.

To decode just do the opposite - copy the long integer, then shift to the left with 32 positions and subtract that from the original integer.